# Firefox Driver not getting any session cookies

Tags: java, cookies, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have some java code written using `Selenium RC` using firefox for the browser that fetches the current session cookies, including a JSESSIONID key.

The way this was done is a simple call like

```
selenium.getCookieByName("JSESSIONID");
```

However when I switched over to FirefoxDriver, it doesn't get anything (it returns `null`)

I tried printing out

```
driver.manage().getCookies().size()
```

But it printed out 0.

Is this a known issue? Are there ways around it without requiring external tools to capture network traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Getcookies only returns cookies for the domain of the current website. Is the current URL different to the domain of the cookie?

Comment: I inspected the cookie using firebug and the cookie's domain is the same as the current website's domain at the time of printing. The cookie's domain is `x.y.z` while the current URL is `https://x.y.z/otherPages`. Note that I am not setting any cookies initially myself, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Cannot you provide the properties of the cookie you are expecting?

Comment: I am not too familiar with cookies. It's not HTTP-only, and expires on session end. What other properties should I be looking for